# PHP redirect if Oracle insert succeeds and fails

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I'm wanting to setup Bootstrap alerts for successful and unsuccessful inserts. I've had a look around and couldn't find any examples of people having 2 redirects one for a successful insert and one for a failed insert.

```
 if(isset($_POST['CountryID'])) {

            $CountryID = $_POST['CountryID'];
            if(isset($_POST['CountryName'])) {
                $CountryName = $_POST['CountryName'];
            }
            if(isset($_POST['GPD'])){
                $GDP = $_POST['GPD'];
            }

            $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO COUNTRY (COUNTRYNAME, GDP) VALUES (:CountryName, :GDP) WHERE COUNTRYID = :CountryID");

            ocibindbyname($stmt, ":CountryID", $CountryID);
            oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":CountryName", $CountryName);
            oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":GDP", $GDP);

            oci_execute($stmt);
            oci_commit($conn);
            oci_free_statement($stmt);

//insert if successful here
            header("Location: ../index.php?Success=Country has been updated!");
//insert else here
            header("Location: ../index.php?Danger=Country update failed!");

    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [`oci_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php)

Comment: Thanks, Nigel, managed to get that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oci_execute($stmt);
$Affected = oci_num_rows($stmt);
oci_commit($conn);


// echo $Gross;
// echo $CountryName;
if(count($Affected) > 0){
    header("Location: ../index.php?Success=$CountryName has been created!");
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?Danger=Country hasn't been created!");
}

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your query such as below

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY
  (COUNTRYID,COUNTRYNAME, GDP)
VALUES
  (:CountryID,:CountryName, :GDP);
```